# C++ header file wrapper library

Tags: c++, c, dll

I am trying to mimick project pattern I saw recently to offer a "C++ binary compatible" API.  I do this by offering a C++ header file wrapper to a pure C interface.  (This is the same trick that the C++ OpenCL wrapper file cl.hpp does with the pure C OpenCL interface.)

Here's a stripped down example.

`foo.h` is the pure C interface:

```
typdef void *foo_t;
extern "C" DLLEXPORT foo_t foo_open(const char *);
extern "C" DLLEXPORT int foo_compute(foo_t, const char *buf, int blen);
extern "C" DLLEXPORT void foo_close(foo_t);
```

`foo.hpp` is the C++ wrapper that also gets distributed with the header:

```
struct Foo {
  foo_t handle;
  Foo() { handle = foo_open(...); }
  ~Foo() { foo_close(handle); }
  std::string compute() {
    char buf[512];
    foo_compute(handle, buf, sizeof(buf))
    return std::string(buf);
  }
}
```

Joe User gets `foo.h`, `foo.hpp`, and `foo.dll` (with an export library).  Foo.dll could have been compiled with MSVC2012, MSVC2013, or mingw, but Joe User can still use MSVC2015.  It all works out since the non-binary portable C++ wrapper implementation is in the public header.

**The problem is:** my wrapper got a little complicated and I wanted to simplify it
by moving the definitions of some of the bigger methods down.  I.e. I want the C++ interface to be concise and listed separate from the implementation (which can be below).

```
// INTERFACE: keep it concise
struct Foo {
  foo_t handle;
  Foo() { handle = foo_open(...) }
  ~Foo() { foo_close(handle); }
  std::string compute(); // keep it concise
}

// IMPLEMENTATIONS: most folks don't need to read this
std::string Foo::compute() {
   char buf[512];
   foo_compute(handle, buf, sizeof(buf))
   return std::string(buf);
}
```

The problem is that if multiple object files include `foo.hpp` (and they will), I end up with multiple definitions of `Foo::compute` since each object file stamps out a copy instead of using the inlined class defined version.

The `cl.hpp` I modeled it after just inlines all the definitions, so that's no help.  I looked around the internet but couldn't find a good example of what I am trying to do, but maybe I am using the wrong nomenclature.

Were these just functions, I'd just mark them all `static` and they wouldn't escape their compilation units.  And worst case, I suppose I could use static helper functions to hack around this.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

REFERENCES:
[1] This is slightly related.  https://chadaustin.me/cppinterface.html

Comment: Why not: `inline std::string Foo::compute() { /* ... */ }`

Comment: Yeah. I thought about this, but can't the compiler ignore `inline`? Even if I get away with it with Compiler A, Compiler B could fail here.

Comment: It can, in the sense of actually compiling an actual function-like body for it, just as it can when you define the function inside the class (which makes it automatically be considered as inline). In both cases however (from [inline specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline)):  "_There may be more than one definition of an inline function in the program as long as each definition appears in a different translation unit. For example, an inline function may be defined in a header file that is #include'd in multiple source files._"

Comment: Use `inline` like dxiv suggests -- with modern compilers, `inline` exists for header libraries to avoid violating the One Definition Rule.  When compilers find multiple definitions of the same inline function, they will try to resolve these into a single version of the function, shared by all callers. This, as opposed to `static`, which gives each translation unit its own private version of the function.  When you hear that `inline` is a "hint" that can be ignored, this refers to its legacy effect of replacing each function call with a direct copy of the function's code.

Comment: The compiler isn't required to actually inline `inline` functions, but it must behave as if it does. (That means accepting multiple definitions from different files, and so on)

Comment: Cool. The 'inline' keyword is exactly what I was after. Would you add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a *thin* wrapper, it makes sense to keep the member functions `inline`. This can be done either by defining them *inside* the class (as in the first snippet of posted code), *or* defining them outside the class and explicitly declaring them as `inline` e.g. in your example:

```
// IMPLEMENTATIONS: most folks don't need to read this
inline std::string Foo::compute() {
    char buf[512];
    foo_compute(handle, buf, sizeof(buf));
    return std::string(buf);
}
```

A function declared as `inline` can be defined in a header file which is #include'd in multiple source files (a.k.a. *translation units*) without ever causing a *multiple definitions* compiler error. Quoting from the docs for [inline specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline):

> There may be more than one definition of an inline function in the program as long as each definition appears in a different translation unit. For example, an inline function may be defined in a header file that is #include'd in multiple source files.

Whether the compiler actually inlines the function or not (in the sense of "expanding" the inline code at each occurrence vs. generating an actual function call) is immaterial to, and does not affect/change, the behaviors guaranteed by the standard for functions declared as `inline`. From the same linked page:

> Since this meaning of the keyword <kbd>inline</kbd> is non-binding, compilers are free to use inline substitution for any function that's not marked inline, and are free to generate function calls to any function marked inline. Those choices do not change the rules regarding multiple definitions and shared statics listed above.